# Getting TypeError when trying to sort data within a d3.csv().then() Promise object using a function outside of the then() method

Tags: javascript, d3.js, es6-promise

I am trying to let users to sort some sports stats data in a D3 visualization I'm working on. I'm using D3v6.

I'm confused as to why I can sort the data using a function outside of the then() method BUT it breaks when I try to use that sorted data.

I've tried to create a minimal implementation of the issue below.
https://codepen.io/sspboyd/pen/rNWgOVr

The `sort_by(val)` function works and will return a sorted array but I get an error if I try to use the newly sorted data within the then() function. The error I'm getting is: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: items is undefined.`

The confusing part is that if I perform the exact same sort operation inside the then() method it works!?!

Here's the code:

```
let svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 600)
        .attr("height", 800);


let player_data = d3.csv('./player_data.csv');

let sort_by = function(val){
    console.log(`Passed in value is: ${val}`);
    player_data.then(function(data){
        let new_data = data.slice().sort((a,b) => d3.descending(+a[val], +b[val]));
        console.log(new_data);
        return new_data;
    });
};

player_data.then(function(data){
    // let sorted_by_Assists = data.slice().sort((a,b) => d3.descending(+a.A, +b.A));

    // data = sorted_by_Assists; // <---- This works. 
    data = sort_by("A");         // <---- This does not work?!?!? Throws error: 
                                 //       "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: items is undefined"


    let player_nodes = d3.select("svg")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(data, d=>d.Player)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", function(d,i){return `translate(10,${i*30})`})
            .attr("class","player_node");

    let player_info = player_nodes
        .append("text")
            .attr("x",0)
            .attr("y",0)
            .attr("dy", "1em")
            .text(function(d){return `${d.Player} - Games Played: ${d.GP}, Points: ${d.P}, Goals: ${d.G}, Assists: ${d.A}`});
        });
```

I'm thoroughly confused so thanks for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line#23 mentioned in codepen pass the resolved `data` to `sort_by` function

```
data = sort_by("A", data);
```

Now `sort_by` funntion will be

```
let sort_by = function(val, playerData){
    console.log(`Passed in value is: ${val}`);
    if(playerData) {
      return sortLogic(val, playerData)
    } else {
      player_data.then(function(data){
        return sortLogic(val, data); 
      });
    }
};

let sortLogic = function (val, data) {
  let new_data = data.slice().sort((a,b) => d3.descending(+a[val], +b[val]));
  console.log(new_data);
  return new_data;
}
```

Comment: @sspboyd please accept the answer, if this resolved your issue

Comment: Thanks for the answer and example code @Bharath. I have clicked accepted for that answer however I am still trying to understand how and why it works. This has lead me down a path to better understand Promises. Currently I'm trying restructure my program's code to work asynchronously. I keep trying to figure out how to 'get the data out of Promise Jail and into a normal variable' but I'm realizing that isn't right mindset (?). Thanks again.